# How can I "shorten"/scale a scene in perspective?

Tags: modeling, mesh, camera, transforms

I'm recreating a specific scene from the manga "Blame!", and I've accurately mapped out the scene in fSpy and imported it into Blender.
The aim of this project is to import it into Unity and be an explorable space. Heres the camera view:

[image: camera view of scene]

I'm currently modeling the rectangle panels on the right, but In order to keep the correct size of the panels, I need to scale each subsequent column by about 1.5x along the Y axis. The fSpy calculated FOV is 52.2 deg.

1.5x every column means that by the 10th panel, instead of a length of 1, it will be about 57.5. This makes for a veeeeery long scene, and I'm unsure how to make it any shorter. My current scene is only 11 columns deep but already 1000m away from the origin (first panel is about 2m long)

[image: side view of the full scene]

perspective:

[image: perspective view]

Comment: Hello ! This looks like a FOV problem, from the looks of it the panels should be the same size, not getting any longer. The first panel looks like it is close to a hundred meters in length, not 2 meters